# Django form wizard: how do you specify views that form a loop?

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to create a form wizard in Django where the second view points back to the first view, and the only way to exit the loop is by clicking a "Finish" button on the second view. Is there any way to do this?

For example:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm1(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    sender = forms.EmailField()

class ContactForm2(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

I would like the next view after ContactForm2 to be ContactForm1, and when you click a "Finish" button on the second view, you complete the form.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#creating-templates-for-the-forms ?

Comment: Thanks for the link! I've read this before, but it seems like the form wizard expects the views to be ordered as a list with no loops. There seems to be no option to create a wizard page that has options for buttons like: "Next page" (where you loop back to page1) and "Finish" (where you exit the wizard from page2). Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks again for the quick response!

Comment: you need to define how many steps you want to take before initializing wizard forms, so it's clearly not possible to do what you want, why not just use formset? I think wizard is an overkill for this.